# How to use ElasticSearch JSON DSL in Java?

Tags: java, python, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm working on a springboot project and having some trouble with ElasticSearch.
The user will put some JSON-format elasticsearch DSL query strings in the database and they are black-box to me. What I need to do is get the query strings and use them so search information in elasticsearch.

In python, the DSL can be a parameter like this:

```
body = {
   "query":{
      "match_all":{}
  }
}
es.search(index="my_index",doc_type="test_type",body=body)
```

How can I perform the search without knowing the details of the string and just using the JSON format query in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are two ways to do it in modern ES client libraries. I haven't tried them myself, but first one seems to be pretty straightforward.

First one is using [low-level client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.9/java-rest-low.html):

```
Request request = new Request("POST", "/index/_search");
request.setJsonEntity(jsonString);
Response response = client.performRequest(request);
```

Seems like it's enough just to push JSON as string into setJsonEntity, and you're already set.

Second one is to use [high level client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.9/java-rest-high.html), and this gets tricky, though it can provide more robust API. As you might know, elasticsearch has concept of XContent, which is serialization/deserialization to/from different formats, including JSON. Theoretically, it is possible to create JsonXContentParser, which then can be used to instantiate SearchSourceBuilder:

```
SearchSourceBuilder.fromXContent(jsonXContentParser);
```

The problem is only that JsonXContentParser requires number of arguments to be instantiated, and i'm not sure how to properly create those dependencies.